# How do i pass a variable to a function thats already being escaped?

Tags: linux, bash, sql

What i want to do is  create multiple informix sql statements & later run them via a bash script.

Here is what i have so far (this works) but is meant to be run from a cron job so it only does one day at a time:

```
echo "
update hst`date --date='yesterday' +%m%d%y` 
   set x = 'GARP' 
 where y in ('CRE', 'LAC', 'SRL', 'JAG', 'JNM', 'BIM')
   and appl = '';
" > update_x_hst.sql
chmod 777 update_x_hst.sql
isql -s history_hst update_x_hst.sql
rm update_x_hst.sql
```

I have to do it this way because the system i am working with creates tables everyday, so i'll have hst070810, hst070910, hst071010, and so on as my tables that i need to update.

I want to do something that will create a sql file and then run it and then go do it again and again for a given number of times, in a for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in {1..11}
do
    echo "
    update hst`date --date='$x days ago' +%m%d%y` 
       set x = 'Complete' 
     where y = 1;
    " > update_x_hst.sql
    chmod 777 update_x_hst.sql
    isql -s history_hst update_x_hst.sql
    rm update_x_hst.sql
done
```

The problem here is it doesnt want to read the variable $x correctly so the statement fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't chmod 777. It's a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes. Change them to double quotes and it'll work.

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in {1..11}
do
    echo "
    update hst$(date --date="$x days ago" +%m%d%y)
       set x = 'Complete' 
     where y = 1;
    " > update_x_hst.sql
    chmod 777 update_x_hst.sql
    isql -s history_hst update_x_hst.sql
    rm update_x_hst.sql
done
```

Also, you should set the permission to something more appropriate. It's not likely that 777 is necessary.

I'm not sure, but you can probably pipe that SQL into `isql` and avoid creating, chmoding and rming a temporary file.

```
echo "something" | isql ...
```

Comment: Thanks that works! You're right about the permissions and piping, i just wanted to work on the hardest part first before going into the nitty gritty.